# "Crew of Two" Completion with DLCs

Tags: achievements, saints-row-the-third

I'm trying to get the 100% of the Steam Achievements for Saints Row the Third, but there's one that I still have a doubt:

> Crew of Two
>
> Complete all instances of Activities in Co-op.

- If you have DLC missions, you also have to complete them on Co-op?
- What if I use City Takeovers?

Answer (score 1):

You must complete all 53 base activities in co-op in order to unlock the achievement- you do NOT have to complete the DLC activity. However, sometimes the game bugs if you have completed an activity in singleplayer first, and will lock you out of the achievement. There is currently no 'kosher' way to fix this; doing so requires a 3rd party tool.